# How to install Ipod Touch Simulator to develop application for it?

Tags: ipod-touch, simulator

I want to develop app for Ipod Touch Simulator, but currently, I don't have Ipod Touch Simulator. I'm try to Google but can't get expect result. Please help me!

Answer (score 3):

1. You need an Intel Mac.
2. Download the [iPhone SDK](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/).
3. The SDK contains the *iPhone* Simulator, not one for an iPod touch.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to be running OS X on an Intel based machine.

You can then download the [iPhone SDK](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/) from Apple which includes the Emulators.